# Xamarin Forms Cards UI design

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.forms

I just started xamarin and got stuck at one point.
[I want to make a design like in the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHsfR.png)
, what should I use and how should I do it?

Comment: have you tried using custom components?

Comment: honestly i don't know how to do it do you have a guide?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  it helps when we can help you with existing code

Comment: That looks like a 2x2 grid to me.  First row spans both columns and contains a label.  2nd row, each column has a StackLayout with a Label and a Switch.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Switch x:Name="styleSwitch" />
<Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit rutrum, enim hendrerit augue vitae praesent sed non, lorem aenean quis praesent pede.">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                     Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference styleSwitch}, Path=IsToggled}"
                     Value="true">
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes"
                    Value="Italic, Bold" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="Large" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

reference from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/switch). PLease check this.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Jason's comment:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="50,50" ColumnDefinitions="200,200">

  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Bildirimier" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

  <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Uygulama Bildirimiera" MaxLines="2" />
    <Switch />
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Mesajilara Izin Ver" MaxLines="2" />
    <Switch />
  </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

Adjust as needed. Look up "Grid", "Label", "StackLayout", "Switch" for further details.